# Graph showing data with from and to date ranges in r

Tags: r, graph, date-range

I have following data of purchase and maturity of investments.

```
investment <- as.character(c("First", "Second", "Third"))
from <- as.Date(c("2019-11-01", "2020-02-25", "2020-06-10"))
to <- as.Date(c("2020-08-31","2021-02-24", "2020-08-09"))
amount <- as.numeric(c(20000,15000,17000))
df <- data.frame(investment, from, to, amount)
```

I want Horizontal Bars with Dates on **X axis**, minimum being the earliest date in the dataset i.e. "2019-11-01" and maximum being the last date "2021-02-24".
investment on **Y axis** i.e. First, Second and Third.

Horizontal bars should appear between the dates as shown (from and to) against each investment, showing different investments covering different period on the X axis.

Mouse hover shall display amount as label.  No relevance of amount on either X or Y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `geom_linerange()` from `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(y = investment, xmin = from, xmax = to ), size = 18,
                 color = "orange") +
  xlab("date")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what exactly I wanted